# Running Selenium in test environment (Symfony+Behat)

Tags: symfony, selenium, testing, behat

Could anybody give some advice for setting Behat with SF4? When I run `behat` database is loaded with fixtures for `test` environment, but Selenium starts browser and tries to find data in `dev` mode. The only way I managed to run Selenium in `test` mode is manually setting `APP_ENV=test` in `.env` or creating `test.php` (copy of index.php) with hardcoded `test` in `$env` and pointing `behat.yml base_url` to `test.php` everything works as expected. But I wanna test Stripe with normal endpoints and having `test.php` is not an option. My current settings of `behat.yml` config https://gist.github.com/mykbas/129a9745476dc75701ae1ee602918abc

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I saw that many devs on github create separate test.php file to run within test environment.

Comment: do you have any example how to do it in SF4?

Comment: I am running currently with the following config behat.yml `Behat\MinkExtension:
 base_url: http://localhost:8000/test.php` and  test.php as copy of index.php with `$kernel = new Kernel('test', true);`

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Do you have test db set up in `config/packages/test/doctrine.yml`?

Comment: Not really, I was just testing a simple functionality, but for the real project there should be a separate database for test environment. Then test.php will definitely recognize settings in packages/test/doctrine.yml